# Custom JavaScript NodeList selector script returning null/undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a small JavaScript selector that will get elements by id, or class depending on the selector, but for some reason it's returning null.

I basically want to test the indexOf of the selector, and run the best selector accordingly. For some reason it's returning null and undefined, any advice is appreciated, jsFiddle below too:

```
var $ = function ( selectors ) {
    var selector = selectors.split( ',' );
    var results = [];

    for( var i = 0; i < selector.length ; i++ ) {
        if ( selector[i].indexOf( '#' ) == 0 ) {
            var result = document.getElementById( selector[i] );
            results.push(result);
        }
    }
    console.log(results);
}

var test = $('#myID');
console.log(test);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6FWL5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the hash before attempting to retrieve the element with `getElementById`. Change

```
var result = document.getElementById( selector[i] );
```

to

```
var result = document.getElementById( selector[i].replace("#", "") );
```

Here's your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6FWL5/1/) back.

Comment: Always the simple stuff. :) Bugs like to hide in plain sight.